# How to split a series of number and compare it with another set of digit?

Tags: abap

Say I have a no. `20101105`, I need to compare it with a series of other nos. say `20110105` , `20090105` and find the nearest no. of it.

I don't want to compare it on the whole, I need to compare it each digit wise by parsing thru it and then see which is the closest.

Can someone suggest on how to do this in ABAP language?

Comment: C is tagged on this question because... ?

Comment: Is there a reason for the seemingly arbitrary restriction on how to perform the comparison (other than this probably being a homework assignment)?

Comment: are you looking for something like the [Levensthein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: BTW: a teacher who would use ABAP in a course interested in things like the Levensthein distance would be a really *mean man*(woman) ...

Comment: I think that you should first obtain the absolute value of the difference between your number and every series of numbers. The nearest would be the least value. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general You should mention some more information. For example, are the numbers really integers ? Then You can put them into an internal table and sorting all of them is the easiest solution to find any "nearest" number relating to an actual scanned. This is just like integers work in sort, they are sorted like numbers, my friend. But If You want it character-wise ( what really makes no sense, if the numbers are integers ) i give You some help with this character-comparison in a do-loop, taking smaller string-length as iterator-counter. I omitted the else, that's Your "homework". :-D

```
  DATA:
    lv_length1  TYPE i,
    lv_length2  TYPE i,
    lv_cnt      TYPE i,
    lv_teststr1 TYPE string VALUE '123456',
    lv_teststr2 TYPE string VALUE '1235'.

lv_length1 = strlen( lv_teststr1 ).
lv_length2 = strlen( lv_teststr2 ).

IF lv_length1 GE lv_length2.
  DO lv_length2 TIMES.
    IF lv_teststr2+lv_cnt(1) NE lv_teststr1+lv_cnt(1).
      BREAK-POINT.
    ENDIF.
    ADD 1 TO lv_cnt.
  ENDDO.
ENDIF.
```

The counter variable is also the index of, in this case, the first not matching character. This gets the job done.
Coded and tested by me just right now.

Comment: uhm ... what? How does this even relate? Is `lv_cnt` supposed to be the *difference*?

Comment: What Do You refer to ?  Your answer ? I had not read it yet, nor Your link.I just pointed out, how to iterate over each char.

Comment: no I was asking how you can decide on this how closely related two numbers are? Certainly the point of the first difference is a very bad indicator

Comment: I bet that the problem is related to maybe bad reads from barcode-scanners or bad user input - you don't care how big the numbers are there

Comment: This is just a sample, of course You can count differences AND positions in the do-loop, basically even percentage , but I provided simple use-case.

Comment: then at least make your answer complete - this does not say how to find the *nearest* element in a number-list to a given number

Comment: It does. At the beginning by the sort. THE OP just needs to provide a bit more information what "nearest" exaclty means.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood but maybe this helps.

```
report  znearest.

data lv_value(8) type n.

parameters p_value(8) type n. " ---------> The value
select-options s_values for lv_value. " -> The list

start-of-selection.

data: wa like line of s_values,
      lv_dif(8) type n,
      lv_nearest(8) type n,
      lv_nearest_dif(8) type n,
      lv_first type c.

loop at s_values into wa.
  lv_dif = abs( p_value - wa-low ). " Calculate the difference

  if lv_first is initial.
    lv_nearest_dif = lv_dif.
    lv_first = 'X'.
  endif.

  if lv_dif le lv_nearest_dif. " Compare the differences
    lv_nearest = wa-low.
    lv_nearest_dif = lv_dif.
  endif.
endloop.

write: 'The nearest from', p_value, 'is', lv_nearest.
```

Hope it helps.